# In Azure Bicep, how do I define a child resource each for multiple existing parent resources?

Tags: azure, azure-bicep

This is my actual use case: I'm writing a Bicep file that adds a subnet to an existing VNET and that should then add corresponding VNET rules to a list of Azure SQL Servers. The SQL Servers should be defined by a configuration parameter.

For those rules, I've tried to use a loop:

```
param azureSqlVnetRules array = [
  {
    azureSqlServerName: 'Azure SQL server accessed by Aks'
    // ... other properties here
  }
]

resource azureSqlServer 'Microsoft.Sql/servers@2021-05-01-preview' existing = [for rule in azureSqlVnetRules: {
  name: rule.azureSqlServerName
  
  resource vnetRule 'virtualNetworkRules' = {
    // VNET rule properties go here
  }
}]
```

This doesn't work because of BCP160: `A nested resource cannot appear inside of a resource with a for-expression.` This limitation is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/loops#loop-limits), "Can't loop a resource with nested child resources."

The docs recommend to "Change the child resources to top-level resources." However, how do I do this in my case? Contrary to the [example given there](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/loops#iteration-for-a-child-resource), I don't want to add many child resources to one parent resource, but one child resource each to many parent resources.

Answer (score 0):

While writing up this question, I actually found a solution, via this blog post: https://ochzhen.com/blog/child-resources-in-azure-bicep#multiple-parent--one-child-resource-per-parent. The idea is to loop twice, using indexes to synchronize the results of the first loop with the second loop:

```
resource azureSqlServers 'Microsoft.Sql/servers@2021-05-01-preview' existing = [for i in range(0,  length(azureSqlVnetRules)): {
  name: azureSqlVnetRules[i].azureSqlServerName
}]

  
resource vnetRules 'Microsoft.Sql/servers/virtualNetworkRules@2021-05-01-preview' = [for i in range(0,  length(azureSqlVnetRules)): {
  parent: azureSqlServers[i]
  // VNET rule properties go here
}]
```