# Azure bicep create multiple API products and link them

Tags: azure, apim

In my main.bicep I have the following call to a module to create api-resources:

```
module apiModule './api.bicep' = {
  name: 'apiDefinition'
  params: {
    apiName: 'myapiName'     
    products: ['product1','product2']
  }
}
```

In the api.bicep I create an `apidefinition` and products:

```
resource apiDefinition 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis@2020-12-01' = {
  name: apiName
  parent: apimService
  properties: {
    path: apiName
    description: '${apiName} API'
    displayName: '${apiName} API'
    format: 'openapi+json'
    value: openapi
    subscriptionRequired: true
    type: 'http'
    protocols: [ 'https' ]
  }
}
```

to create the products I use a for-loop to iterate the products input parameter :

```
resource Product 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/products@2020-12-01' = [for product in products: {
  name: prodcuct
  parent: apimService
  properties: {
    approvalRequired: true
    description: 'product for ${apiName} apis'
    displayName: '${product}-Product'
    state: 'published'
    subscriptionRequired: true
  }
}]
```

Now I need to link those 2 products to my API:

```
resource apiproductlink 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/products/apis@2020-12-01' = {
  name: apiName
  parent: Product 
}
```

-> this will not work since parent: Product is not a single resource, it has 2 products. And it seems not possible to iterate over the previous create products to iterate.

So my question : How can I link one API to multiple products ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/products/apiLinks` bicep module ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.apimanagement/service/products/apilinks?pivots=deployment-language-bicep)). e.g.

```
resource productLinks 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/products/apiLinks@2023-03-01-preview' = [for i in range(0, length(Product)): {
  name: 'api_someApi_${products[i]}'
  parent: Product[i]
  properties: {
    apiId: 'https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/${subscription().subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/${resourceGroup().name}/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/${apimName}/apis/${apiName}'
  }
}]
```

Referenced this post for the index retrieval of parentes: [In Azure Bicep, how do I define a child resource each for multiple existing parent resources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70758360/in-azure-bicep-how-do-i-define-a-child-resource-each-for-multiple-existing-pare)